# Actionscript 3 - String Replace characters with MML?

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, twitter, fdt

First of all: I'm new to programing. Please be detailed if you choose to help me.

What i'm trying to do is to first of all remove all special characters from a hard coded tweet. What I want to do after is to convert each letter into a specific tone, using MML (Music Macro Language).

When i play the tweet via the sound library sion after my attempted replacing i only get five tones through. What am I doing wrong? I'm guessing it's simple, but I don't know **anything**.

I'm coding Actionscript 3 in FDT, which is all very new to me, as is regexp.

```
public function translateTweet() {
    var myPattern:RegExp = /[~%&\\;:"',<>?#]+/g;
    var tweet : String = "@cupofjoakim AN EXAMPLE string! :D #hi11expo";

    tweet = tweet.replace(myPattern, " ");

    // maybe i could take away a lot of the code for removing the 
    // special characters? dont dare to do it now, but still.
    myPattern = /[~%&\\;:"',<>?#]+/g;
    trace(tweet.replace(/[~%&\\;:"',<>?#]+/g, ""));

    // Now that Special characters should be gone, let's translate the rest!
    trace(tweet.replace(/\s/g, "r4"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/a/g, "o4c"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/b/g, "o4d"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/c/g, "o4e"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/d/g, "o4f"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/e/g, "o4g"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/f/g, "o4a"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/g/g, "o4b"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/h/g, "o5c"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/i/g, "o5d"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/j/g, "o5e"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/k/g, "o5f"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/l/g, "o5g"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/m/g, "o5a"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/n/g, "o5b"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/o/g, "o4c"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/p/g, "o4d"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/q/g, "o4e"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/r/g, "o4f"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/s/g, "o4g"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/t/g, "o4a"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/u/g, "o4b"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/v/g, "o5c"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/w/g, "o5d"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/x/g, "o5e"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/y/g, "o5f"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/z/g, "o5g"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/A/g, "CAPS_A"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/B/g, "CAPS_B"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/C/g, "CAPS_C"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/D/g, "CAPS_D"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/E/g, "CAPS_E"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/F/g, "CAPS_F"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/G/g, "CAPS_G"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/H/g, "CAPS_H"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/I/g, "CAPS_I"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/J/g, "CAPS_J"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/K/g, "CAPS_K"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/L/g, "CAPS_L"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/M/g, "CAPS_M"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/N/g, "CAPS_N"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/O/g, "CAPS_O"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/P/g, "CAPS_P"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/Q/g, "CAPS_Q"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/R/g, "CAPS_R"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/S/g, "CAPS_S"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/T/g, "CAPS_T"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/U/g, "CAPS_U"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/V/g, "CAPS_V"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/W/g, "CAPS_W"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/X/g, "CAPS_X"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/Y/g, "CAPS_Y"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/Z/g, "CAPS_Z"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/å/g, "o4c"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/Å/g, "o4c2"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/ä/g, "o4c"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/Ä/g, "o4c2"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/á/g, "o4c"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/Á/g, "o4c2"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/à/g, "o4c"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/À/g, "o4c2"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/é/g, "o4g"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/É/g, "o4g2"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/è/g, "o4g"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/È/g, "o4g2"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/ë/g, "o4g"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/Ë/g, "o4g2"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/ú/g, "o4b"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/Ú/g, "o4b2"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/ù/g, "o4b"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/Ù/g, "o4b2"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/ü/g, "o4b"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/Ü/g, "o4b2"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/í/g, "o5d"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/Í/g, "o5d2"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/ì/g, "o5d"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/Ì/g, "o5d2"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/ï/g, "o5d"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/Ï/g, "o5d2"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/ó/g, "o4c"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/Ó/g, "o4c2"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/ò/g, "o4c"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/Ò/g, "o4c2"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/ö/g, "o4c"));
    trace(tweet.replace(/Ö/g, "o4c2"));
}
```

Comment: I have no idea about actionscript, but it seems not to be a regex problem to me (Maybe the way you call the regexes is wrong). But in general, you need to debug your code. Means either you are using an IDE with an integrated debugger, where you can see what your string looks like before and after the replacement, or you just print out the value before and after the replacement. This way you can find the point where something goes wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you are trying to do, but I do know that String.replace() will return a new String with the replaced contents and not touch the one you sent in, so you will need to go:

```
tweet = tweet.replace(/\s/g, "r4");
```